# Sharepoint workflow - check event is update or create

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I've attached a sequential workflow to a list which is fired whenever an item is created or updated. Is there a way to check whether the event responsible is an update or create event?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that you can do via SharePoint designer. What you can do is create a hidden boolean field which is blank/false. Then on create you set it to true. Then you can use that to tell if it is an update or create based on the value of the field.

Comment: i'm using Visual Studio instead of SP Designer